# Not able to click on mat-checkbox using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to click to checkbox especialy mat-checkbox but without success.

It doesn't matter what type of locator I'm using, the result is:

> "Failed: No element found using locator: ....."

The rest page elements I'm able to locate.
I attach html and part of my spec.js

html:

```
<mat-checkbox _ngcontent-xmg-c24="" class="checkbox mat-checkbox mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="acceptTerms" id="mat-checkbox-1">
  <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="mat-checkbox-1-input">
    <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container mat-checkbox-inner-container-no-side-margin">
      <input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-checkbox-1-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">
      <div class="mat-checkbox-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="">
        <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-checkbox-frame">
      </div>
      <div class="mat-checkbox-background">
        <svg xml:space="preserve" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark" focusable="false" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" fill="none" stroke="white"></path>
        </svg>
        <div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="mat-checkbox-label">
      <span style="display:none">&nbsp;
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
</mat-checkbox>
```

spec.js

```
it('Registration', async function (){
    await homePage.clickRegistration();
    await registrationPage.fillEmailAddress(email);
    await registrationPage.fillPassword(password);
    await registrationPage.fillPassword2(password);
    let checkbox = element(by.css("input[formcontrolname=acceptTerms]"));
    expect(checkbox).toBeDefined();
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(checkbox).click().perform();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
await checkbox.click();
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?